# Form doesn't excecute Post Request Function properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

For Some Unknown Reason this form just won't make the proper POST request as set in the Send() function , Can't Figure out why, tried everything.

The `$http.post(url,data,callback);` function works I tested it via the console with the same data but somehow when it's called onsubmit nothing happens. The POST request does not happen and server does not receive or log anything.
Can Anyone offer some insights on this mystery?

The Server is Node with Express // Let's just say this is how server handles post request , just to test

```
  app.post('/signin',function (req,res) {
   res.send('It works!');
   console.log(req.body);
  });
  app.post('/signup',function (req,res) {
    res.send('It works!');
    console.log(req.body);
  });
```

This is the HTML Form

```
  <div class="auth-form">

  <label class="auth-form-tab">Sign In</label>
  <label class="auth-form-tab">Sign Up</label>

  <form onsubmit="Send();return false;">
    <input type="text"  name="username"  placeholder="Username">
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text"  name="lastname"  placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="email" name="email"     placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <div class="status"></div>
 </div>
 <script src="/js/auth.js">
```

Here is the JS, ignore the `AppScope.ActiveTab` thing it should not affect anything

```
function Send() {
  if (AppScope.ActiveTab == 'SignIn') {
    $http.post('/signin', AppScope.FormData, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = data;
    });
  } else {
    $http.post('/signup', AppScope.FormData, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = data;
    });
  }
}
var AppScope = {
  ActiveTab: 'SignIn',
  Status: '',
  FormData: {
    username: document.querySelector('input[name=username]').value,
    firstname: document.querySelector('input[name=firstname]').value,
    lastname: document.querySelector('input[name=lastname]').value,
    email: document.querySelector('input[name=email]').value,
    password: document.querySelector('input[name=password]').value
  }
};

var $http = {};

$http.serialiseObject = function (obj) {
  var pairs = [];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) == '[object Object]') {
      if (obj[prop] !== null) {
        pairs.push($http.serialiseObject(obj[prop]));
        continue;
      }
    }
    if (obj[prop] !== null) pairs.push(prop + '=' + obj[prop]);
  }
  return pairs.join('&');
};

$http.post = function (url, data, callback) {
  if (url == undefined) return Error('URL undefined');
  if (data == undefined) return Error('can\'t send nothing');
  var Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  Req.open('POST', url, true);
  Req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  Req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (Req.readyState == 4 && Req.status == 200) {
      var response = 'response' in Req ? Req.response : Req.responseText;
      if (callback) {
        callback(response);
      } else {
        Error('No Callback Found');
      }
    }
  };
  Req.send($http.serialiseObject(data));
};
```

Comment: you say it **won't make the proper POST request**, but is clicking submit doing anything at all - like can you see that Send() is called?

Comment: yes , earlier I had it console.log() something from the function and it did but the POST request still does not go through , don't know why

Answer (score 0):

in  AppScope.FormData: {

use document.querySelector not document.querySelectorAll - the latter returns a collection of elements, thus, no value

On second thoughts, that AppScope.FormData will be "populated" on page load, so all those values will always be as at page load, not changed if the user enters new values in the input fields

edit: so, you edited the original code to use querySelector ... I take it that it still doesn't work

Comment: I use a binding system that sets form data on interaction
    inputElement.addEventListener('keyup',SetFormData);
    inputElement.addEventListener('changes',SetFormData);
    inputElement.addEventListener('click',SetFormData);

Comment: I can only go by what you've shown - the first part of my answer is still relevant - use querySelector for a single element, querySelectorAll returns a list, so you cant get the .value